# i am generating the pdf using mpdf from html and now i have to show pdf inside pdf

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf, mpdf

show pdf inside pdf

i am generating the pdf using mpdf from html, the problem that i am facing its that i have images and i can show them using img src, but i need to show the pdf inside the pdf

i have pdf files that i have to show inside the pdf file

with href the user can download the pdf inside the the report pdf file

any ideas?

this is the code i tried so far a nothing seems to work :

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url().'get_image.php?i='.$plan_dir.$plan['file'];?>">Download PDF</a>

<a href="<?php echo base_url().'get_image.php?i='.$plan_dir.$plan['file'];?>"><embed src="<?php echo base_url().'get_image.php?i='.$plan_dir.$plan['file'];?>" width="500" height="375"></a>

<embed src="<?php echo base_url().'get_image.php?i='.$plan_dir.$plan['file'];?>" width="500" height="375">


<div id="pdf">
<object width="400" height="500" type="application/pdf" data="<?php echo base_url().'get_image.php?i='.$plan_dir.$plan['file'];?>" id="pdf_content">
<p>Insert your error message here, if the PDF cannot be displayed.</p>
</object>
</div>  

<object data="<?php echo base_url().'get_image.php?i='.$plan_dir.$plan['file'];?>" type="application/pdf" width="300" height="200"> alt : <a href="<?php echo base_url().'get_image.php?i='.$plan_dir.$plan['file'];?>">test.pdf</a>
</object>

<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=<?php echo base_url().'get_image.php?i='.$plan_dir.$plan['file'];?>&embedded=true" style="width:718px; height:700px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. You talk about images and being able to show them with img src then say immediately after you need pdf in pdf. Do you want to link to a pdf from within another pdf? Or do you want to embed a pdf within another pdf?

Comment: embed a pdf within another pdf

Answer (score 0):

Try using URL with `http`, for example:

http://example.com/image.jpg or http://127.0.0.1/project/image.jpg

instead of base_url()...

---

To use the link, try using `name`

For example:

```
<a name="http://example.com" target="_blank">DESCRIPTION</a>
```